# Why does my Wifi connection drop when AP changes channel?

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi connection halts when the AP changes channel. When it happens, i need go into wifi settings and reconnect to the network. At home i have managed to get around the problem by fixing the channel to 10 in the router, with no drops as a result. However, this obviously only works in cases where i have access to the router. Is there a way to fix this issue? it happens in ubuntu, not windows. Do i have the wrong driver? Some setting?
lshw -C network:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: 99
   serial: 48:a4:72:be:c1:cf
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: 

       broadcast=yes 
       driver=iwlwifi 
       driverversion=5.9.0-050900-lowlatency 
       firmware=29.1654887522.0 
       7265D-29.ucode ip=100.68.12.123 
       latency=0 
       link=yes 
       multicast=yes 
       wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: Windows probably just reconnects automatically when the AP changes. Is your WiFi connection set to connect automatically?

Comment: it does connect automatically on boot. when the problem occurs, the WiFi doesn't actually disconnect, i just get a ? icon instead of the signal strength indicator.